# Bounded-input bijections of infinite sequences

Tags: puzzles, ct.category-theory, topology

Here is a puzzle I haven't managed to solve. I would like to know if this problem is already known, or has an easy solution.

It is possible to define a bijection $ 3^\mathbb{N} \cong 5^\mathbb{N} $ using the properties of bicartesian closed categories. Andrej Bauer posted an explanation of what this means on his blog as "[Constructive gem: juggling exponentials](http://math.andrej.com/2009/09/09/constructive-gem-juggling-exponentials/)".

This bijection has an interesting property: it is "bounded-input" meaning that each component of the output depends only on boundedly many components of the input. However, for $k,l\geq 2$ it seems that this construction can only show that $ k^\mathbb{N} $ and $ l^\mathbb{N} $ are isomorphic if $k$ and $l$ are both odd or both even. This leaves open the question:

Is there a bounded-input bijection from $ 2^\mathbb{N} $ to $ 3^\mathbb{N} $?

Here is a short note describing the problem in more detail:
[A conjecture concerning bounded-input bijections of infinite sequences](http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~cmcq/rec/bib.pdf).

Definitions:

A function $f : \prod_{i \in I} X_i \rightarrow \prod_{j\in J} Y_j $ is *bounded-input* if there exists
an integer $k$
such that each component of the output of $f$ depends only on at most $k$
components of the input.
More formally, $f$ is bounded-input if for each index $j \in J$
there are indices $i_1,\dotsb,i_k \in I$
and a function $f_m : X_{i_1}\times\dotsb\times X_{i_k} \rightarrow Y_j$
such that for all $x \in X$ the component
$f(x)_j$ equals $f_j(x_{i_1},\dotsb,x_{i_k})$.

A bijection $f$ is a *bounded-input bijection* if
it is a bounded-input function.

A bijection $f$ is a *bounded-input isomorphism* if
it and its inverse are bounded-input functions. This is also interesting.

Comment: It is probably better to copy the definition of “bounded-input bijection” from your note.  I misunderstood the definition until I read it.

Comment: Done. I would like to point out that while the question's motivation comes from category theory semantics, the puzzle itself is combinatorial.

Comment: The most annoying thing about this problem is that it looks easy!  All sets $(2k)^{\mathbb{N}}$ are bounded-input isomorphic to each other, and so are all sets $(2k+1)^{\mathbb{N}}$.  I cannot see any reason why these two cannot be made bounded-input isomorphic by using a variation of the isomorphisms used in the existing proofs, but such attempts seem to fail.  Aghh.  (I have no experience in this field, so I may be off the mark.)

Comment: I really like this conjecture, and it's been hanging out for a month now.  I'll give a bounty to anyone who solves it or makes substantial progress in either direction.

Comment: Although it's not quite the same setup, the construction used at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2935/examples-in-which-the-size-of-the-alphabet-geq-2-used-for-an-encoding-matter seems related to this question.

Comment: The construction I used in my question may look similar, but it deals with injections and surjections, not bijections. Also, the conditions involved deal with prime factorisations, not odd-even-ness.

Comment: @Alex ten Brink: That's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer :). They might still give someone some inspiration though.

Comment: @Colin McQuillan: Please consider posting a placeholder answer, so if there is no significant progress by the end of the week, I can award the bounty to you for asking a cool question.

Comment: Nice question :-) By the way, what is the "simplest" isomorphism between $2^\mathbb{N}$ and $3^\mathbb{N}$ that you know of?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a CS theory guy. But in ergodic theory this type of mapping is known as *finitary* isomorphisms. For example people considered if two Bernoulli sequences of the same entropy is finitarily isomorphic or not. For example (this is one-sided shift because it seems you are concerned with $P^{\mathbb{N}}$ rather than $P^{\mathbb{Z}}$):

A. Del Junco, “Finitary codes between one-sided Bernoulli shifts,” Ergodic
Theory Dynamical Systems, vol. 1, pp. 285–301, 1981.

P.S. I intend to leave this as a comment but I cannot due to lack of reputation. Let me know if it is completely off-topic then I will delete it.

Comment: I for one welcome any wacky brainstorming ideas at this point.

Comment: Note that whether the indices are taken from ℕ or ℤ is irrelevant in this question.

Comment: I've awarded the full bounty to this answer, because, if I did nothing, the answer would receive half the bounty anyway, as the most upvoted (and having received at least two votes).  If someone posts a full or partial proof at a later date, and I see it, I'll probably start another bounty, to award rep to the solver.

Answer (score 0):

I think an isomorphism between $k^\mathbb{N}$ and $2^\mathbb{N}$ should be provided by any collection of exclusive and exhaustive binary prefixes of size $k$, for example for $k = 3$ we could us "0", "10", and "11".  In more general, we can use "0", "10", "110", ..., "11...10", "11...11" where the second to last has $k - 2$ ones and the last has $k - 1$.

The exclusive and exhaustive nature allows us to define the inverse ($2^\mathbb{N} \to k^\mathbb{N}$) in the obvious fashion.

The boundedness in the forwards direction is easy since each input digits provides at least one output digit the $i$th binary digit is easily determined by no more than the first $i$ $k$-ary digits.

The boundedness in the backwards direction is a little uglier.  With the prefix collection I gave above each $k$-ary digit "reads" from at most $k$ binary digits and so the $i$th $k$-ary digit is determined by no more than the first $k i$ binary digits.

Comment: This is not bounded-input in either direction.  According to the definition of a bounded-input function, you need a _uniform_ bound on the number of input variables which each output variable depends.  In the forward direction of your mapping, the i-th output variable depends on the first i input variables, so there is no uniform bound.  In the backward direction, the i-th output variable depends on the first ki input variables.

Comment: D'oh.  I'm going to go read the question for the 1.5th time.  :(